# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter N must be positive at StdRandom.uniform(StdRandom.java:119)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, maze

I am new to this website so correct me if there is anything wrong with my question. I keep receiving this error and I am not entirely sure what is wrong with my program:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter N must be positive

```
at StdRandom.uniform(StdRandom.java:119)
at Maze.chooseRandomlyFrom(Maze.java:52)
at Maze.expandMaze(Maze.java:136)
at Maze.main(Maze.java:193)**
```

I ran the JUnit test in my IDE (eclipse) however I could not trace where the error is coming from. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated and thank you for taking the time to check out the code. Here is what I am working with. I included comments for each method as clearly as I could.

```
public class Maze {
public static final int EAST = 1;
public static final int NORTH = 0;
public static final int[][] OFFSETS = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, 0 } };
public static final int SOUTH = 2;
public static final int WEST = 3;

  //Purpose: Modifies passage to contain a one-way passage from location a to location
  //b. Assumes these two locations (arrays of two numbers) are adjacent.
  //Parameters: boolean[][][] passages, int[] a, int[] b
  //Return: N/A
public static void addPassage(boolean[][][] passages, int[] a, int[] b) 
{
        int ax = a[0];
        int ay = a[1];
        int bx = b[0];
        int by = b[1];
        if (by == ay + 1) {
          passages[ax][ay][0] = true;
        } else if (bx == ax + 1) {
          passages[ax][ay][1] = true;
        } else if (by == ay - 1) {
          passages[ax][ay][2] = true;
        } else {
          passages[ax][ay][3] = true;
        }
}

  //Purpose: Gets array of pairs containing start and all locations in the list. 
  //Parameters: int[] start, int[][] list
  //Return: Returns a new array of pairs containing start followed by all of the locations in list.
public static int[][] addToFront(int[] start, int[][] list) 
{
    int[][] path = new int[list.length + 1][];
    path[0] = start;
    for (int i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
      path[i] = list[(i - 1)];
    }
    return path;
}

  //Purpose: Gets random one from the first element of the list
  //Parameters: int[][] list, int n
  //Return: Returns a random one of the first n elements of list.
public static int[] chooseRandomlyFrom(int[][] list, int n) 
{
    return list[StdRandom.uniform(n)];
}

  //Purpose: Gets pair and compares to first number as one of the first n element 
  //Parameters: int[] pair, int[][] list, int n
  //Return: Returns true if pair, assumed to be an array of two numbers, has the same 
  //numbers as one of the first n elements of list.
public static boolean contains(int[] pair, int[][] list, int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          if ((pair[0] == list[i][0]) && (pair[1] == list[i][1])) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
}

  //Purpose: Will draw the maze
  //Parameters: boolean[][][] passages
  //Return: N/A
public static void drawMaze(boolean[][][] passages) 
{
    StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.PINK);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
    int width = passages.length;
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.75 / width);
    // Draw passages
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            if (passages[x][y][NORTH] || (y + 1 < width && passages[x][y + 1][SOUTH])) {
                StdDraw.line(x, y, x, y + 1);
            }
            if (passages[x][y][EAST] || (x + 1 < width && passages[x + 1][y][WEST])) {
                StdDraw.line(x, y, x + 1, y);
            }
        }
    }
    // Draw entrance and exit
    StdDraw.line(0, 0, -1, 0);
    StdDraw.line(width - 1, width - 1, width, width - 1);
    StdDraw.show(0);
}

  //Purpose: Will draw the maze solution
  //Parameters: int[][] path, int width
  //Return: N/A
public static void drawSolution(int[][] path, int width) 
{
    StdDraw.setPenColor(); // Black by default
    StdDraw.setPenRadius();
    StdDraw.line(0, 0, -1, 0);
    StdDraw.line(width - 1, width - 1, width, width - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        StdDraw.line(path[i][0], path[i][1], path[i + 1][0], path[i + 1][1]);
    }
    StdDraw.show(0);
}

  //Purpose: Checks if here's neighbor in direction (called there) is in unexplored. If so, adds a passage from here 
  //to there and returns there. If not,returns null.
  //Parameters: boolean[][][] passages, int[][] unexplored, int n, int[] here, int direction otherwise.
public static int[] expandLocation(boolean[][][] passages, int[][] unexplored, int n, int[] here, int direction) 
{
    int[] there = new int[2];
    here[0] += OFFSETS[direction][0];
    here[1] += OFFSETS[direction][1];
    if (contains(there, unexplored, n))
    {
      addPassage(passages, here, there);
      return there;
    }
    return null;
}

  //Purpose: Chooses "here" to be either lastExploredLocation (if it is not null) or a random location in 
  //frontier. If possible, adds a passage from "here" to a location "there" in unexplored, then moves "there" from unexplored to
  //frontier. If not, moves "here" from frontier to done.
  //Parameters: boolean[][][] passages, int[][] done, int[][] frontier, int[][] unexplored, int[] counts, int[] lastExploredLocation
  //Return: N/A
public static int[] expandMaze(boolean[][][] passages, int[][] done, int[][] frontier, int[][] unexplored, int[] counts, int[] lastExploredLocation) 
{
    int[] here;
    if (lastExploredLocation == null) {
      here = chooseRandomlyFrom(frontier, counts[1]);
    } else {
      here = lastExploredLocation;
    }
    int direction = StdRandom.uniform(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      int[] there = expandLocation(passages, unexplored, counts[2], here, direction);
      if (there != null)
      {
        frontier[counts[1]] = there;
        counts[1] += 1;
        remove(there, unexplored, counts[2]);
        counts[2] -= 1;

        return there;
      }
      direction = (direction + 1) % 4;
    }
    done[counts[0]] = here;
    counts[0] += 1;
    remove(here, frontier, counts[1]);
    counts[1] -= 1;
    return null;

}
  //Purpose: Draws then solves maze
  //Parameters: String[] args
  //Return: N/A
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int width = 20;
    StdDraw.setXscale(-0.5, width - 0.5);
    StdDraw.setYscale(-0.5, width - 0.5);
    StdDraw.show(0);
    boolean[][][] passages = new boolean[width][width][4];
    // Initially, no locations are done
    int[][] done = new int[width * width][];
    // The frontier only contains {0, 0}
    int[][] frontier = new int[width * width][];
    frontier[0] = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    // All other locations are in unexplored
    int[][] unexplored = new int[width * width][];
    // Number of nodes done, on the frontier, and unexplored
    int[] counts = { 0, 1, width * width - 1 };
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            if (x != 0 || y != 0) {
                unexplored[i] = new int[] { x, y };
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    // As long as there are unexplored locations, expand the maze
    int[] lastExploredLocation = null;
    while (counts[2] > 0) {
        lastExploredLocation = expandMaze(passages, done, frontier, unexplored, counts, lastExploredLocation);
        drawMaze(passages);
        StdDraw.show(25);
    }
    // Solve the maze
    int[][] solution = solve(passages, new int[] { 0, 0 }, new int[] { width - 1, width - 1 });
    drawSolution(solution, width);
}

  //Purpose: Modifies list so that pair is replaced with the (n - 1)th element of list. Assumes pair is an 
  //array of two numbers that appears somewhere in list. Thus, when this method is done, the first n - 1 element of list are
  //the same as the first n elements of the old version, but with pair removed and with the order of elements potentially different.
  //Parameters: int[] pair, int[][] list, int n
  //Return: N/A
public static void remove(int[] pair, int[][] list, int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          if ((pair[0] == list[i][0]) && (pair[1] == list[i][1]))
          {
            list[i] = list[(n - 1)];
            return;
          }
        }
}

  //Purpose: Gets a return path from start to finish
  //Parameters: boolean[][][] passages, int[] start, int[] goal
  //Return: Returns a path (sequence of locations) leading from start to goal in passages or null if there is no such path.
public static int[][] solve(boolean[][][] passages, int[] start, int[] goal) {
    if ((start[0] == goal[0]) && (start[1] == goal[1])) {
          return new int[][] { goal };
        }
        for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
          if (passages[start[0]][start[1]][d] != false)
          {
            int[] next = { start[0] + OFFSETS[d][0], start[1] + OFFSETS[d][1] };
            int[][] restOfPath = solve(passages, next, goal);
            if (restOfPath != null) {
              return addToFront(start, restOfPath);
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, `counts[1]` went wrong at somewhere.

Comment: I wonder when this `counts[1] -= 1;` in `expandMaze` will produce a negative number ... may took a while, since its initial value is `1`.

Comment: It passes it on line 52 when `counts[1]` is equal to 0. Don't allow it to pass 0 as the second parameter to `chooseRandomlyFrom()`.

Comment: @BethanyLouise Or you can check the parameter and deal with it in `chooseRandomlyFrom`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the argument 'n' to 
StdRandom.uniform() at Maze.chooseRandomlyFrom(Maze.java:52) the argument you are passing is negative.  According to the error message, the parameter must be positive.  This could be because during expandMaze, you are assigning counts[1] to be one less than its current value (counts[1] -= 1;), which will eventually result in a negative number.   It would appear that the method is called over and over as long as counts[2] > 0, which in some cases must be the case for enough iterations such as counts[1] becomes a negative number.

Perhaps before calling this StdRandom.uniform() method, you should take the absolute value of counts[1] to ensure it is always positive.  Math.abs(counts[1]) should do the trick.